# Hazelcast - What are write and read methods of Map property for Portable serialization

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am implementing portable serialization in Hazelcast. I am saving a java object(Employee) to hazelcast, which contains a property of type **Map**. What methods to be used to serialize this **map** property here?

```
public class Employee implements Serializable, Portable {
    private String name;
    private Map<Integer, Address> addresses;

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public int getFactoryId() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getClassId() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writePortable(PortableWriter writer) throws IOException {
        writer.writeUTF("name", name);
        // how to write addresses field here
    }

    @Override
    public void readPortable(PortableReader reader) throws IOException {
        name = reader.readUTF("name");
        // how to read addresses field here
    }
}
```

Map value 'Address' also implements Portable and has required read and write methods.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do this directly, since you would need a Map implementation that also implements Portable. Unfortunately, Hazelcast doesn't seem to provide one.

You could however use PortableCollection instead. Wrap your map into an instance of PortableCollection at write time by calling the constructor and passing the Map.entrySet() result, which is a collection. At read time, create the Map instance from the de-serialized values. Pay attention, however, that by doing so the individual map values are not serialized in a Portable format! The raw serializer is used instead.

If you want Portable serialization for the whole thing, I guess you'll have to implement a Portable Map yourself.

(using Hazelcast 3.7.3 here)

Answer (score 0):

@JavaCodeNet, If `Address` is not `Portable`, after writing all your primitive & `Portable` objects, you can call `writer.getRawDataOutput()` which will return you an `ObjectDataOutput`. Using that, you can  call `writer.getRawDataOutput().writeData(addresses)` if `Address` implements Java Serializable.

If not & it implements other Hazelcast serialization interfaces like `DataSerializable` or a 3rd party serializer, then you need sore item count first and iterate through the map & serialize entries separately using same `writer.getRawDataOutput()` metmod & do the same while reading.